# M1 MacBookpro install brew

Tags: redis, homebrew

when I install brew completely ,then I want to process "brew install redis",there is a problem "Error: Failed to download resource "openssl@1.1"
Download failed: [https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl%401.1-1.1.1k.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz"](https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl%401.1-1.1.1k.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz%22)